# Is it possible to read data from a csv file sequentially in jmeter while performing concurrent requests?

Tags: performance, concurrency, jmeter

I have created a CSV file with 200 data. While performing concurrent requests (i.e ramp-up period 0 secs), I want the requests to be performed in the same sequential order as present in the file because an ID from the response data of the current API has to be used in sequential order in the request body of another API.

Details in my thread group:

No of threads(users) - 200

Ramp-up period - 0

Loop count - 1

I want the data in csv file to be read sequentially i.e row1, row2, row3... and so on

Comment: @user7294900 can you please suggest how can this be done? Currently, the sequence is being maintained only when the ramp-up period is increased i.e  about 100 secs.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are mutually exclusive because you want concurrency and sequential execution at the same time.

Actually threads are reading data sequentially, the reason you're seeing "randomness" is due to your application response time distribution, if application response time will be 1 ms - the process of reading test data will be sequential.

In general it shouldn't have any impact because as per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) `JMeter Variables are local to a thread` so if you have 2 [samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) one after another each thread will execute the sampler on top first and the sampler on bottom second and all the context (variables, cookies, cache, etc.) will remain.

Whatever, if despite all above points you still looking for a way of sequential reading data by multiple concurrent threads you will have to switch to [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead), something like:

```
${__CSVRead(test.csv,0)} ${__CSVRead(test.csv,next)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information (and another feature): [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime)